# Using SSL with elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront, elastic-load-balancer

I want to use SSL with my elastic beanstalk applications. I have 4 of them in a VPC. I created a certificate in the certificate Manager.

What I was able to do activate load balancers for each application so I where I can activate the SSL support.

However 4 Load Balancers are quite expensive for an Enviroment that is main for testing so I configured the Cloudfront to do a https routing to my service, resulting in an error if I do not use a load balancer..

My Question is. How can I use a SSL certifcate without paying 4 Load Balancers each month?

They cost me 3 times the amount of my EC2 instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Anyone stumbling over this Question.

The solution is to make your own Nginx Configurations. Make a forward to https. With letsencrpyt you can get a certificate. For more info:
https://gist.github.com/tony-gutierrez/198988c34e020af0192bab543d35a62a